# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, activity

После запуска apk на xiaomi redmi note 2 выдает такую ошибку.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apps.gragas.storydirector/com.apps.gragas.storydirector.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2489)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2551)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:169)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5572)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:968)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:763)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.apps.gragas.storydirector.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
... 21 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070078
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1446)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:146)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:230)
at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:188)
... 24 more
```

Тем не менее на эмуляторе ошибок не возникает

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="#F5FFFA"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Styles

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Перечитал кучу решений по схожим проблемам, но попытки избавиться от краша программы не увенчались успехом.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону "рыть"?

Comment: Вы скорее всего используете графику с большим разрешением для Floating button.

Comment: удалите ресурс для теста 
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" из фаба, если спасет, напишите что за иконка ic_add (вектор, пнг, етс)

Comment: `ic_add` у Вас кастомная вектор картинка?

Comment: @Chaynik  app:srcCompat заведомо подразумевает под собой использование вектор картинки. Да и дело в том, что app:srcCompat автоматически подгонят картинки под нужный размер, в отличии от android:src, но это если вектор картинка используется

Comment: Какое минимальное API используете? если < 21, то есть ли ` vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`?

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070078` -- откройте APK в AS -> Build -> Analyze APK и найдите в `resources.arsc` имя ресурса по ID. Там уже будет яснее с чем проблема.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. У меня в качестве графики стояла xml. Поставил png-картинку, скопировал ее так же из drawable-v24 в drawable и все заработало.

Comment: @iFr0z app:srcCompat добавлен для векторов, но это не значит, что только для них. при этом нужно учитывать не только, что это вектор, но и что внутри самого вектора (с 5.0 есть поддержка векторов, но некоторые атрибуты вектора поддерживаются в более новых api). Собственно наводку автору мы дали, и он решил свою проблему.